# Using the OnPaint() method

Tags: c#, winforms, qr-code, onpaint

I am using [this library](https://qrcodenet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GraphicsRenderer&referringTitle=Renderer) to generate QRcode into a WinForm application, but I don't really know how to take use of the OnPaint() method.

So I have this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  public Form1()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
  {
    QrEncoder encoder = new QrEncoder(ErrorCorrectionLevel.M);
    QrCode qrCode;
    encoder.TryEncode("link to some website", out qrCode);

    new GraphicsRenderer(new FixedCodeSize(200, QuietZoneModules.Two))
                             .Draw(e.Graphics, qrCode.Matrix);

    base.OnPaint(e);
  }

  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    this.Invalidate();
  }
}
```

I have a simple pictureBox in the form and I just want to generate the QRcode image in there (if it is possible to generate it in a picturebox).

Comment: With this code you are painting directly smowhere onto Form1.

Comment: I think this link might help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're putting your image in a picturebox and you're only producing your image once, then you don't need to worry about the paint method (you're not doing an animation etc, it's just a QR code)

Just do this in your form load (or where ever you produce your image)

```
mypicturebox.Image = qrCodeImage;
```

**Update - additional code to facilitate your library**

```
    var bmp = new Bitmap(200, 200);
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        new GraphicsRenderer(
            new FixedCodeSize(200, QuietZoneModules.Two)).Draw(g, qrCode.Matrix);
    }
    pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

Comment: But there is not method in the library with a return type Image, so I can assign it to the picture box. 

I also tried with `pictureBox.Invalidate()` (so it's not "wherever in the form" but still no result).

Comment: Excellent! Now I can easily save the generated image physically as a bitmap file. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I eventually did:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public event PaintEventHandler Paint;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.pictureBox_Paint);
            this.Controls.Add(pictureBox1);
        }

        private void pictureBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            QrEncoder encoder = new QrEncoder(ErrorCorrectionLevel.M);
            QrCode qrCode;
            encoder.TryEncode("www.abix.dk", out qrCode);

            new GraphicsRenderer(
                new FixedCodeSize(200, QuietZoneModules.Two)).Draw(e.Graphics, qrCode.Matrix);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Although that works, it will be repeated every time the form is re-drawn.  I've updated my answer above - if you put that code in your form load (or button click etc), then you'll just produce your QR image once - hope that helps :)